# All my WordPress pages are redirecting to Xampp's homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, xampp, permalinks

I have a local Xampp stack setup for my WordPress site.  It was first installed on another web server(clients web server) and im doing work on it locally.  So I downloaded all the files and database to my local Xampp server.  So here is what I did to run it locally to begin with:

1. first I changed the URL in the database table: wp_options for the siteurl.
2. Then I added these two lines of code to the end of my wp-config:

   ```
   define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/wpsite');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wpsite');
   ```

Those are the only changes I made to run it locally.  Also, in the root of the WordPress site folder, there is this .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have tried all options:

1. commenting out all combinations of the wp-config.php file's define lines.
2. deleting the .htaccess file with combinations of all the define lines in wp-config.php file.

Also the homepage and admin urls are fine.  It's the permalinks that aren't working. For instance http://localhost/wp_site/about redirects to Xampp's homepage and if the .htaccess file is deleted it gives Xampp's default 404 error page.

Comment: change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /wpsite` in htaccess

Comment: ok i did that, still did not work.

Comment: make sure you don't have any redirect plugin installed, because wordpress normally generates 404 error if something problem in url, not redirecting to home page.

Comment: try with disable all plugins.

Comment: ok i tried deactivating all plug-ins and still it did not work..

Comment: Have you by any chance hardcoded the URLs in Appearance >> Menus? Try testing with a different browser as well.

Comment: check your menus page in the backend. urls can be static there.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this issue by navigating to **Settings > Permalinks** in the WP admin, scrolling to the bottom, and clicking "Save Changes", an idea I got from [this WP forum page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-cant-find-my-new-pages/), to regenerate the permalinks.

For the whole transfer process, I followed [these instructions](https://www.ionos.com/community/websites-ecommerce/wordpress/copy-wordpress-website-and-safely-test-locally/#article-comments) exactly and then at the very end resolved the issue making the permalinks change I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is behaving proper as per changes made by you. You just changed the base URL and hence it is not working for other pages which is obvious thing.

See, changing just site base URL is not enough while migrating a site from one set up to another, each of your old URL should be replaced by its respective new URL.

Tweak in `.htaccess` may help you temporarily but that is something which will just keep on redirecting your pages. Once you are done with development on your local system, you might be needing to move the changes back to live server. So, making permanent changes in DB will be more proper than making changes in `.htaccess`.

I would suggest to undo what have you done so far or simply start making a new set up as per following guidelines -

- Copy your WordPress files to your localhost e.g. in 'wpsite' folder (without .htaccess file).
- Export DB from your live set up (can use PhpMyAdmin)
- Import the DB in your localhost set up (can be done using PhpMyAdmin or
  MySQL dump).
- Replace all the URLs
  Can use a tool like this https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
  You can put the search and replace PHP file in your WP root directory and run through the browser. Follow the steps and all the URLs will be replaced.
- Login to your new set up.
- Recreate the `.htaccess`.

Done.

OR

You can also make use of this plugin to do activities like above in more automatic way https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

Comment: omg...i appreciate the answer but theres got to be a more better way with respect to my situation...i mean with what i got so far what should i do next?  other than what you just stated...i don't have time for all that...

Comment: hmm... you don't have that much time. I think, rest of the things you have already done, now you just have to replace the URLs. Just run the search and replace tool and that's it. Should not take much time. The time which you are spending here can be used for this thing.. I think, you should just do it and recreate the .htaccess from WP dashboard.

Comment: This is indeed a very well explained answer +1

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I've followed the instructions here (https://www.ionos.com/community/websites-ecommerce/wordpress/copy-wordpress-website-and-safely-test-locally/) which seem to match what you suggest @WisdmLabs, other than the fact that you exclude the `.htaccess` file and those instructions do not. I also followed the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238826/links-redirect-to-dashboard-xampp) but now instead of seeing the XAMPP welcome page, I get a 404 from Apache. How should I recreate the `.htaccess` file and why should that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

follow These steps
1. Delete htaccess file
2. Delete cache folder if cache folder exist in wp-content folder
3. Do permission of wp-content folder writable.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the URLs are being cached. Now that you're hosted on localhost, the old URLs are invalid. Login to wp-admin and pick "Delete Cache" option if you're using WP Super Cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out that my index,php was the cause. I changed it to the default wordpress index.

Default index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Answer (score -3):

The other Wordpress solutions/suggestions on this page did not even touch all the possible URLs related to the site in the database.  A quick

```
`SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_value = 'home url for your site'`
```

found two records where your site's url and home url are set. All I had to do what to change both of those fields to my local setup URLs - that was it.

Comment: if you are saying that you just had to change the old URLs with your localhost URLs, then I'm not getting what have you tried to say with the statement '1) first I changed the url in the database table: wp_options for the siteurl.' in your question. As per this statement what were your new URLs that you put. I thought, you have properly updated those URLs with localhost URL and you are facing issue with other URLs on the site. You yourself creating problems for you and solving by yourself and we just wasted our time over here :(

Comment: "All your "expert" wordpress solutions/suggestions did not even touch all the possible urls related to the site in the database". Please don't tell me, if you would have replaced URLs and this would have not covered automatically?

Comment: no u didn't read/listen correctly to the first part:  i said i set only one record in the db to the local url, the siteurl option, but the not home option.

Comment: Hi Dave. May I offer some feedback? I don't know the history of this question, but it is quite common to ask a question on _Stack Overflow_ and then find the answer oneself. In my view this is a form of [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). The attack previously in this answer, on people who helped you, was therefore unwarranted, and I have excised it in lieu of asking a moderator to do so.