# links redirect to dashboard xampp

Tags: wordpress, redirect, xampp, dashboard, permalinks

I've moved WordPress from hosts to Xampp local hosts.

I corrected the links inside the database. Although the home page is loaded.
But on every link, I'm redirected to the http: // localhost / dashboard page.

I use WordPress 4.9.6, Xampp 3.2.2 and Windows 8.1 64-bit

my .htaccess file

```
BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
END WordPress
```

please guide me, thanks

Comment: I found answer  RewriteRule . FOLDERNAME/index.php [L]

Answer (score 7):

For me, changing the `.htaccess` file as @Ustav suggested did not resolve the issue. After making that change, while I was no longer redirected to the XAMPP dashboard, I was instead redirected to a 404 page from Apache.

What *did* resolve the issue for me was simply navigating to **Settings > Permalinks** in the WP admin, scrolling to the bottom, and clicking "Save Changes", an idea I got from [this WP forum page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-cant-find-my-new-pages/). That immediately fixed it, no changes to `.htaccess` required.

The remote-to-local transfer instructions I followed can be found on [this 1&1 Ionos instruction doc](https://www.ionos.com/community/websites-ecommerce/wordpress/copy-wordpress-website-and-safely-test-locally/#article-comments)

Comment: This worked for me as well. 
1)Set up WordPress on Xampp, created site folder in htdocs. 
2)In wp-config.php I also added: 
/** Define new homepage **/
define('WP_HOME', 'https://localhost/mynewsite/');
define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME . '/');
3) In exported sql file I changed all URLs pointing to live site to https://localhost/mynewsite/
4) Reinstalled WordPress
5) Your solution of "Settings > Permalinks" helped to navigate to other pages of backed up site

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Go to htaccess file.

Inside

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...
</IfModule>
```

Put this code 
RewriteRule . FOLDERNAME/index.php [L]

Comment: For me, the /dashboard page no longer showed up, but I instead got a 404 from Apache, so it didn't fully resolve the issue